# cursor movement performance problem in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings

I opened a very large file by emacs, and I found it is too slow to go to the top of the buffer by hit `M-<`. And I also found that it is normal when I enter the command `goto-line 1`. So I want to override the default keybinding like:

```
(defun hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly ()
  "Go to beginning of the buffer quickly"
  (interactive)
  (goto-line 1)
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<") 'hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly)
```

Then a weird situation happened. It is still very very slow when I hit `M-<`. But it is normal when I directly hit `M-x hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly`. I can not explain how this come? Do you ever come to this problem?

Comment: How big is the file? Emacs can become a bit slow when viewing really large files. Does this also happen when you run emacs as `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: around 20k line

Comment: That shouldn't cause any problems with jumping to beginning or end of file. Try opening the same file with `emacs -Q` and report if it's slow again

Comment: It is normal when -Q is added, but I need my configuration, and my question is why there is difference when global-set-key is used and not?

Comment: What happens if you bind it to another key entirely? And how slow is it otherwise? (more precisely, have you seen the operation complete?)

Comment: `goto-line` does a **lot** of fancy processing. If all you want to do is go to the beginning of the buffer, then `M-x goto-char 0` is all you need.  You can bind `(lambda () (interactive) (goto-char 0))` to a key, if you like.

Comment: Maybe `M-x goto-line` is only fast because you performed it after doing `M-<`. Try `M-<` `M->` `M-<`, is the second `M-<` faster?

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298375/global-set-key-performance-in-emacs) and this site at the same time.  Please pick one site or the other.

Comment: We know you need your configuration. The fact that the problem only occurs when you use your configuration, and not with `emacs -Q`, tells us that there is something in your configuration that causes the problem. The answer will be finding and fixing that problem, not using `emacs -Q` from now on.

Comment: Now that it is known it is your configuration which is causing the problem, you need to look more closely at what major and minor modes you are using and the other configuration settings you have.  One thing which might help is to provide some more details on your setup. for example, the modes which are being loaded and the type of data etc

Answer (score 0):

After I have checked init.el, I found that it is the problem of linum-mode.

I tried to disable global-linum-mode, and it goes fine.

So I wrote a shortcut:

```
(defun hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly ()
  "Go to beginning of the buffer quickly"
  (interactive)
  (global-linum-mode 0)
  (goto-line 1)
  (global-linum-mode 1)
  )
(global-set-key [(meta <)] 'hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly)
```

Comment: Please consider editing your question regarding how to properly (more efficiently) circumvent a problem with `linum-mode`, and include what you have tried.  This *answer* should be deleted as it is inefficient at best.

Comment: Maybe you can try using [`nlinum-mode`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html) instead? It claims to be (hopefully) faster.